# Pythonのエラーの原因を教えてください

Tags: python

`inputs = data[:,0:1]`がエラーなんですけどどうしたらよいでしょうか(画像は使っているデータセットです）

**実行環境:**
Google Colab

**ソースコード:**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import linear_model
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.linear_model import Lasso
with open("Mjob(使うデータ).csv", 'r') as file:
 line = file.readline()
 data = np.loadtxt(file, delimiter=',', usecols=(1,2)

inputs = data[:,0:1]
outputs = data[:,-1]

#標準化
scaler = StandardScaler()
scaler.fit(inputs)
x_scaler = scaler.transform(inputs)

#regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()
regr = Lasso()
regr.fit(inputs, outputs)
#regr.fit(x_scaler,outputs)

print('Coefficients: \n', regr.coef_)

predict = regr.predict(inputs)
#print('R2 score:{0}'.format(r2_score(outputs,predict)))
print('Coefficients:\n',regr.coef_)

# plot
"""x_min = np.min(inputs)
x_max = np.max(inputs)
plot_x = np.arange(x_min,x_max,0.1)
plot_x = plot_x[:,np.newaxis] # convert [*,*,*,..] ->[[*],[*],[*],...]
plt.scatter(inputs[:,0], outputs, color='black')
plt.plot(plot_x[:,0], regr.predict(plot_x), color='red')
plt.show()
"""
```

Comment: その上の行の`np.loadtxt(`の括弧が閉じていませんね。(最後の`)`が不足している) それが解決したとしても問題があるようなら、再現・調査のためには必要とするデータ(`Mjob(使うデータ).csv`)の内容か入手方法についても記述しておいてください。

Comment: 「エラーが出た」という事実だけを伝えるのではなく、実際に表示されたエラーメッセージも質問に含めてみてください。

Comment: 「inputs = data[:,0:1]がエラーなんですけどどうしたらよいでしょうか」とのことですが、エラー全文を質問に追記してください。

Comment: Google Colabだったかで以前本当に1行しかエラー表示が無いと書かれた質問があったので、これもそうかもしれませんね。1行程度しかエラーが表示されないなら、デスクトップPCのローカル環境を構築してテストしてみることをお勧めします。そうすれば詳細なエラーメッセージが表示されるでしょう。